# Which STL to use to find index by value in O(1) in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Say I have an array `arr[] = {1 , 3 , 5, 12124, 24354, 12324, 5}`

I want to know the index of the value `5`(i.e, 2) in `O(1)`.
How should I go about this?

P.S :
1. Throughout my program, I shall be finding only indices and not the vice versa (getting the value by index).
2. The array can have duplicates.

Comment: O(1) is not possible with an array. O(lg n) is the best you can get if the array is sorted.

Comment: Because in the lookup, 5 comes first

Comment: O(1) is possible if the index is always 2.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` would be the nearest one.

Comment: Consider I also need an STL when no duplicates is available. What shall I use?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that someone, somewhere, has formally proven that you cannot just know the index of any element in an unordered sequence without major constraints. Will you be adding elements to that sequence through the lifetime of the program? If so, can you afford O(N) insertion?

Comment: I can relax only till O(logn) insertion..

Comment: Your question "which STL" doesn't make sense, as STL is a name of a certain (obsolete) library. Check out the description of the STL tag for further info.

Comment: If that input array is all you are allowed to have, then the problem has no solution. Any attempts to produce something better than `O(n)` will require either preprocessing of the original array or an addtional data structure (with preprocessing to build it). Are you allowed to go that way?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Who says that the STL is obsolete? If anything, it's one of the most actively developed parts of the standard library.

Comment: In your example, the value 5 is present at index 2 and index 6. So when you request the index of 5, do you expect to get all of them or only the first. Also, will you be adding more items to the array after indexing it ? If so, will you be inserting elements in the middle (thus changing the index of the following elements), or only at the end ?

Comment: @gen-y-s Elements will be added at end. When I query 5, I expect to only the first..

Comment: @PrasathGovind in that case you can use unordered_multimap (C++11 only) with the value as the key, and the position index as the value.

Comment: @ThePcLuddite, please look at the homepage of the STL. There hasn't been a release for ages. There isn't going to be one either, because large parts of the STL have been incorporated into the C++ standard. The STL is effectively dead, albeit well remembered. And no, I'm not following your claim that "it's one of the [...] parts of the standard library", because that is like saying that Boost is part of the standard library.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt If you check out the description of the STL tag for further info, you'll find that "When C++ was standardised, large parts of the STL were adopted into the Standard Library, and these parts in the Standard Library are also sometimes referred to collectively as 'the STL'."

Comment: You should have read the whole thing, @ThePcLuddite, because there it also says: "Note that the name STL is ambiguous, as it may refer to different things." and then goes on to explain why. Just because other people use the term ambiguously doesn't convince me to do the same.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Well, whether you like it or not, that's how people are using it. Words change meaning. I did read the whole thing, and even though it says that referring to this part of the standard library as the "STL" is incorrect *strictly speaking*, it goes on to say that "in practice people rarely need to refer to the HP library, and so 'STL' is nearly always used to describe the STL-derived parts of the standard library". You can't fault the OP for using the tag correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee there are no duplicates in the array, you're best bet is probably creating an `unordered_map` where the map key is the array value, and map value is its index.

I wrote a method below that converts an array to an `unordered_map`.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void arrayToMap(const T arr[], size_t arrSize, std::unordered_map<T, int>& map)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i) {
        map[arr[i]] = i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1 , 3 , 5, 12124, 24354, 12324, 5 };
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map;

    arrayToMap(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr), map);

    std::cout << "Value" << '\t' << "Index" << std::endl;
    for(auto it = map.begin(), e = map.end(); it != e; ++it) {
        std::cout << it->first << "\t" << it->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, in your example you use the value `5` twice. This causes a strange output in the above code. The outputted map does not have a value with an index `2`. Even if you use an array, you would be confronted with a similar problem (i.e. should you use the value at 2 or 6?).

If you *really* need both values, you could use `unordered_multimap`, but the syntax for accessing elements isn't easy as using the `operator[]` (you have to use `unordered_multipmap::find()` which returns an iterator).

```
template <typename T>
void arrayToMap(const T arr[], size_t arrSize, std::unordered_multimap<T, int>& map)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i) {
        map.emplace(arr[i], i);
    }
}
```

Finally, you should consider that `unordered_map`'s fast look-up time O(1) comes with some overhead, so it uses more memory than a simple array. But if you end up using an array (which is comparatively much more memory efficient), searching for a specific value is guaranteed to be O(n) where n is the index of the value.

---

Edit - If you need the duplicate with the lowest index to be kept instead of the highest, you can just reverse the order of insertion:

```
template <typename T>
void arrayToMap(const T arr[], size_t arrSize, std::unordered_map<T, int>& map)
{
    for(int i = arraySize - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        map[arr[i]] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. I think the OP's comments indicate that the lowest index should be returned when there are duplicates. Your code just needs to reverse the order of insertion and it will achieve this.

Comment: @Keith That's a simple adjustment. I added that just in case the OP thinks it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::unordered_map` from C++11 to map elements as key and indices as value. Then you can get answer of your query in **`amortized O(1)`** complexity. `std::unordered_map` will work because there is no duplicacy as you said but cost you linear size extra space.

If your value's range is not too large, you can use an array as well. This will yield even better `theta(1)` complexity.

Comment: How does `std::set` looks in those comparisions?

Answer (score 1):

use unordered_multimap (C++11 only) with the value as the key, and the position index as the value.